# jQuery Ajax to run a script

Tags: jquery, ajax, intervals, shoutcast

I have a script that runs in an iframe every 90000 miliseconds and reloads the page.

My issue -
1. I want to override the 90000 miliseconds to 9000 miliseconds
2. I also want to execute it as ajax

Below is the script, it is inserted in the head of my webpage.

```
<script src="http://www.shoutcast-tools.com/shoutcast/codes/get/6451/" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Did you *write* this script or is this just something you've found?

Comment: You can't run a script **as Ajax** Do you know what Ajax is?

Comment: The script is from shoutcast-tools. It displays as an iframe in my code when I inspect the webpage with my browser.

Comment: @Yoric You should contact Shoutcast Tools to modify it.  Even if you are permitted to override it, then can always change their code and break yours, since there isn't an API for making the change you want.